# Minor mistake computing $\int \frac{1}{x^3+2x^2-3x} \; dx$?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to compute:

$$\int \frac{1}{x^3+2x^2-3x} \; dx$$

Until now, I did the following: Factoring:

$$x^3+2x^2-3x=x(x-1)(x+3)$$

To obtain the parcial fractions:

$$\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{x+3}+\frac{c}{x-1}=\frac{1}{x(x-1)(x+3)}$$

$$a(x-1)(x+3)+bx(x-1)+cx(x+3)=1$$

$$-3 a + 2 a x - b x + 3 c x + a x^2 + b x^2 + c x^2 = 1$$

This give me the system:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  {a+b+c}&=&{0} \\ 
  {2a-b-3c}&=&{0} \\ 
  {-3a}&=&{1} 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Solving it yields:

$$a= -\cfrac{1}{3}\quad b=\cfrac{5}{6} \quad c=-\cfrac{1}{3}$$

And then:

$$\int \frac{-1/3}{x}+\frac{5/6}{x+3}+\frac{-1/2}{x-1} \; dx$$

$$\int \frac{-1/3}{x} \; dx+ \int \frac{5/6}{x+3}dx+ \int \frac{-1/2}{x-1} \; dx + C$$

$$\frac{-1}{3}\int \frac{1}{x} \; dx+ \frac{5}{6} \int \frac{1}{x+3}dx+ \frac{-1}{2} \int \frac{1}{x-1} \; dx + C$$

Which should be:

$$\frac{-1}{3} \log(x)+ \frac{5}{6} \log(x+3)+ \frac{-1}{2} \log(x-1)+ C$$

But Mathematics gives me:

$$\frac{1}{4} \log (1-x)-\frac{\log (x)}{3}+\frac{1}{12} \log (x+3)$$

But I have no idea of what I did wrong.

Comment: Another quick comment, you're missing absolute values.

Comment: You don't verity $a+b+c=0$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be $2a-b+3c=0$, not $2a-b-3c=0$.

As a side note, if you want to solve $a(x-1)(x+3)+bx(x-1)+cx(x+3)=1$, then it's a lot easier to plug in $x=0, 1, -3$ instead of expanding.

Comment: Oh, thanks. When I expanded it in the board, I (wrongly) found $-3c$. Now I expanded it with Mathematica and obtained the right result but didn't pay attention.